# Common APIs in C or C++ for the IoT

Tags: standards, system-architecture

What are the common or usual APIs (or libraries) in C or C++ for the IoT, in the sense of having a documentation, a set of programming interfaces? (Like e.g. POSIX is for operating systems, Qt is for GUI, etc....).

This [short page](http://gcc-melt.org/IoT-03-interest-Starynkevitch.html) motivates my question (I'm interested in developing static source code analysis tools for IoT). I'm not only looking for legal standards, but also for commonly used APIs or libraries -in C or C++, with existing *header* files for them- in various industrial domains. I'm not interested in [Web API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API)s (conventions defining some HTTP requests) or just in network protocols without any API or library implementing them.

<sup>(so I am not interested in developing myself IoT applications, but I want to develop software engineering tools working & analysing source code to help developers of IoT software)</sup>

I could even be interested by industry specific IoT APIs or libraries, e.g. in healthcare, logistics, transportation, smart grids, smart buildings, etc; as long as as it is a C or C++ API or library.

---

I am in a research group working on static source code analysis, and we would like to develop tools analyzing C or C++ source code, to help the IoT software developer.

<sup>However, I need to find out a way to be funded before working on this.</sup>

We suggest to develop a specialized tool (preferably open source, above existing technologies), for developers & engineers writing source code (in C, C++, and Ada if needed...) targeting IoT platforms. This tool will be integrated in the targeted software development kit. This tool could assist IoT software developer by analysing and checking the validity of the source code against coding rules, invariants, and good practices specific to these software frameworks. The main objective is to enhance the software quality and to accelerate the time to market. If relevant, the tool could perform specific source code optimizations to enhance the software performance and/or to decrease the code size.

---

NB. This [IoT Eclipse](https://iot.eclipse.org/standards/) webpage is listing several standards. I am interested in APIs & libraries implementing them (and any other IoT de facto domain specific standard), if developing source code analyzers for them is worthwhile.

Comment: @Basile Will this be commercial or FOSS? In any case, is there any way that we can follow your progress. I realize that might take months, or even years, so a UTL to watch or a mailing list would be very welcome

Comment: I am mostly working on free software since a dozen of years, so I hope it would be FOSS. However, I need to join some consortium (or to get some R&D grant, or any other funding) to begin working on this.

Comment: Do you mean things like CMSIS? http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/General/html/index.html

Comment: [MQTT](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html) and Mosquitto is quite popular when it comes to IoT. Maybe the [Libmosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html) API is a good target for your code analyzer?

Comment: @BenceKaulics: Do you know some people (notably in Europe) in the libmosquitto community? If yes, please forward them this. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any aspect of IoT in particular you're interested in? There's the communication side as Bence Kaulics suggested (MQTT, CoAP, 6LoWPAN etc) or there are entire IoT platforms like [Android Things](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/index.html) or [Ubuntu IoT](https://www.ubuntu.com/internet-of-things). Which part do you want to tackle?

Comment: I am quite open, as long as it is about static source code analysis of IoT code.

Answer (score 8):

Basile, I think that we are missing a fine distinction here.

When you speak of a Posix like standard for IoT, I think that you are speaking of libraries which wrap a protocol.

As one who has been employed for (*cough*) decades implementing protocol stacks for telephony and satellite communication, I can say (as you are probably aware) that these protocols are, by need, already strictly defined.  For instance, Zigbee is governed by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.15.4

These standards lay down the messages to be transmitted and define that byte 0 means this, bytes 1 through 4 mean that, etc, so that devices from disparate manufactures can communicate with each other (that’s the theory, anyway; I could tell you some horror stories ;-)

As I said, for any given protocol, there can be a plethora of manufactures. And for any given manufacturer, there can be multiple software libraries, which is your problem.

Your task is too difficult as long as there are multiple APIS available, which wrap each protocol.

Sadly, there will only be a Posix-like API only if one company becomes dominant. There might be a thin possibility if a major government throws a lot of money at it, but I can’t see that happening. The only other chance I as Linux-like effort by the Open Source community.

---

Btw, I don’t think that you make it clear enough that your will not be just another static code analyser, that it is not intended for general code, but for certain specific APIs. You do say that, sort of, but not explicitly enough, IMO. When you define that exactly, you will know what your project really is.  If you already know, you don’t seem to emphasize it (but maybe I am not reading well enough, rushed between two meetings).

The syntax of POSIX APIs is policed by the compiler, as will be the syntax of any APIs which you study. So I guess that you are looking for potentially dangerous code , such as use of unitiatlized resources, not freeing allocated resources, etc – is that correct?

It sounds like a great project, though, and I have starred this question.

---

[image]

Comment: I am more interested in the semantics of the APIs (not only or mostly of their *syntax*). And yes, I would like to analyze code using that API for the things you mention (and much more). This is currently just a rough idea (and I will adapt it to the needs), and I'm still trying to find ways (notably collaborative R&D projects) to get it funded.

Comment: BTW, the Qt example shows that an API (and a library) can become important -and perhaps dominant- even without being a legal standard.

Answer (score 5):

As quick response, I don't think that for IoT there is a special type of library, I would say that IoT is basically the "*new embedded systems*", they just changed the name and added the connection to the cloud.

So answering to what I use for C++ programming, my reference page is http://www.cplusplus.com/

Basically for IoT you will need **communication libraries**, whatever protocol you uses (USB, TCP/IP, UDP, ZigBee, etc, etc.)

In addition, if you have communication then you need **security/encryption**.

And the rest will depend on what part of hardware you are controlling or measuring. You will need the **libraries (API/Firmware) for such hardware**.

Surely there are many things I am missing here... let's see others answers

Comment: So basically, you are confirming my gross intuition that IoT is just the new buzzword for embedded computing, probably embedded Linux systems?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It depends on the device class. Fitness trackers (as opposed to watch mounted phone extensions) do not run Linux. Self-powered nodes do not run Linux. Hub nodes, which perform distributed sompute) probably do run Linux. Hence my talk of a stack extending from edge to the cloud.

Comment: That is ok. So what are the *commonly used* APIs or libraries on these devices.

Comment: Since ZigBee looks like a network protocol, it is out of scope. However, a commonly available API in C or C++ *implementing* ZigBee would be interesting

Answer (score 5):

The standards for various networking protocols are already well defined.  What it sounds like you're hoping to find is an API implementing standard behaviors inherent to IoT devices.  Something like a Light() function that can turn lights on, off, or dim them to a fraction of their brightness; DoorSensor() that can be armed or disarmed, or can register for an alert on door open or door close events; that sort of thing.  However, I am not aware of any API library that isn't application specific.

If anyone has one, you might find something in [Domoticz](https://domoticz.com).  It's an open source home automation controller written in C++.

Answer (score 4):

Embedded, plus secure communications, plus provisioning (device management) plus OTA updates. This is a big software package and also emerging as a new type of platform for developing on.

There are several providers offering cloud solutions, they will typically have their own client APIs and chosen endpoint operating systems.

As far as I can tell, the various wireless protocols do not really dictate any particular software stack, so your choice needs to be driven by the big picture, not the client APIs. One deciding factor may be if open-source is important for the stack in your application.

Comment: I'm not developing IoT applications, but I want to develop static source code analysis tools for the benefit of IoT software developers.

Comment: OK, so there are (guessing) 4 or 5 different stacks that are relevant and you need to consider all of them if you want to be following whichever two or three become dominant in a few years time.

Comment: What precise APIs or libraries (in C or C++) are you thinking of? Please name them in your answer!

Comment: if you happen to know some team working on such APIs please forward them my question and point them http://gcc-melt.org/IoT-03-interest-Starynkevitch.html

Answer (score 3):

I think your objective is somewhat similar to BOOST:

[Boost C++ Libraries](http://www.boost.org/)

They aim to establish "existing practice" and provide reference implementations so that Boost libraries are suitable for eventual standardization.

Perhaps Boost could be a major player in IoT: it certainly has made some great improvements to C++.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54420/discussion-on-answer-by-serup-common-apis-in-c-or-c-for-the-iot).

Answer (score 2):

IoTivity is the reference implementation of the [OCF Specification](https://openconnectivity.org/). You can find documentation and source code at [their GitHub repository](https://github.com/iotivity/iotivity/).

[From their list of features](https://www.iotivity.org/documentation/features):

> - Core functionality written in C for deployment to constrained devices
> - Most functionality available from C and C++

Their [Framework APIs](https://www.iotivity.org/documentation/architecture-overview) allow discovery, data transmission, data management (collection, storage and analysis) and device management (e.g. provisioning, diagnostics) over various protocols such as Bluetooth, Wi-Fi, ZigBee and Z-Wave.